# EOF encountered inside an action LEX program

Tags: flex-lexer, yacc, lex, eof

I have a lex program as follows. I encounter the error

> EOF encountered inside an action LEX program

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[ \t]+ ;
[0-9]+ {yylval = atoi(yytext);
 return INTEGER;}
[-+*/] {return *yytext;}
"(" {return *yytext;}
")" {return *yytext;}
\n {return *yytext;}
. {char msg[25];
 sprintf(msg,"%s <%s>","invalid character",yytext);
 yyerror(msg);}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that file.  The error usually means you have a missing `}` but in this case, I copied the data from your question onto my machine and flex compiled it without complaint. Is it exactly the same as your file?

Answer (score 5):

This error often occurs if you have an EOF at the end of the text without terminating the last line with an end-of-line, but it can also be system dependent, making it hard to reproduce on other systems.

Ensure there is a blank line after the last line and the error is likely  to go away.